# breaking main loop - jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using jstree library to display a tree.

In the code below, I am looping through the selected nodes in the tree and based on some conditions, I am assigning a variable 'allow_edit' a boolean value.

I would like to break the main loop if `'allow_edit = false'.`

I tried using label and breaking the loop but this does not seem to work. I am getting undefined label.

```
loop1:
$j.each($j("#demo2").jstree("get_selected"), function(index, element) {

  var selected_node_depth = parseInt($j(element).attr('node_depth'));
  var allow_edit = false;


  var array_first_filter = $j.grep(array_first, function(v) { return v[1]  != "not detected";})
  var array_second_filter = $j.grep(array_first_filter, function(v) { return v[3] > selected_node_depth;})


  if (array_second_filter.length === 0 || array_second_filter.length == null)
  {
    allow_edit = true;
  }
  else{
    alert("Confliction exists in your selected terms.");
    allow_edit = false;
    //break loop1; /** not working, getting undefined label **/
  }


}
```

Any suggestions on how to break the main loop if `'allow_edit = false'`? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function you pass to `.each()` returns `false`, the iteration will stop.

```
else {
  allow_edit = false; // pointless since you're about to return ...
  return false;
}
```

Also, as a programming style note, any construction of the form:

```
if (something) {
  flag = true;
}
else {
  flag = false;
}
```

can be better written as simply:

```
flag = something;
```

In JavaScript, to *force* `flag` to be boolean (`true` or `false`), you can do this:

```
flag = !!(something);
```

The two `!` (logical "not") operators force the expression ("something") to be evaluated as a boolean by the same rules as are used when that expression is the test clause of an `if` statement.